# Sorting a structure by multiple columns in C

Tags: c

Consider a simple `struct`

```
typedef struct test {
int num;
double val;
} test;

int main()
{

test test[5]={ {5,4.3}, {1,0.9}, {1,0.3}, {1,3.2}, {5,1.1}};

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    printf("%d: %f\n", test[i].num, test[i].val);
}
    return 0;
}
```

How do we sort it by the first column and then the next one?

**Intended Output:**

```
1: 0.300000
1: 0.900000
1: 3.200000
5: 1.100000
5: 4.300000
```

Comment: `qsort()` is the way you sort any array of objects. Simply write a compare function that provides a comparison on the `num` members and you are good to go.  [Short Recent Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895815/3422102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to using `qsort()` is writing the compare function. The prototype is:

```c
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
```

Don't let your eyes roll back in your head. `a` and `b` are just pointers to elements of the array that will be compared in the `compare()` function. The function returns `-1` if `a` sorts before `b`, `0` if they are equal, and `1` if `b` sorts before `a`. All you need to do with `a` and `b` is cast to the proper type and then make the desired comparison (ascending, descending, etc..).

In the case you have two values you wish to compare, you simply compare the first, and if they are NOT equal, you provide a return indicating how they should sort on the first value. (your `.num` member) If the first values with `a` and `b` ARE equal, then you provide a return based on the comparison of the second value (your `.val` member).

You can write the `compare()` function as:

```c
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    test *x = (test *)a,
         *y = (test *)b;
    
    /* if ->num not equal, sort by ->num */
    if (x->num != y->num)
      return (x->num > y->num) - (x->num < y->num);
    
    /* otherwise, sort by val */
    return (x->val > y->val) - (x->val < y->val);
}
```

A short example that sorts the `test` array (renamed `arr`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test {
  int num;
  double val;
} test;

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    test *x = (test *)a,
         *y = (test *)b;
    
    /* if ->num not equal, sort by ->num */
    if (x->num != y->num)
      return (x->num > y->num) - (x->num < y->num);
    
    /* otherwise, sort by val */
    return (x->val > y->val) - (x->val < y->val);
}

int main()
{

  test arr[]={ {5,4.3}, {1,0.9}, {1,0.3}, {1,3.2}, {5,1.1}};
  size_t nmemb = sizeof arr/sizeof *arr;
  
  qsort (arr, nmemb, sizeof *arr, compare);
  
  for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++){
      printf ("%d: %f\n", arr[i].num, arr[i].val);
  }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsortstruct_test
1: 0.300000
1: 0.900000
1: 3.200000
5: 1.100000
5: 4.300000
```

Read the link I posted in the comment and the answer here and let me know if you have further questions.