# May the program not sort the array because of didSwap?

Tags: c

**Minimal, reproducible example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
    int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
    int nums[10] = {0, 1, 9, 7, 8, 4, 3, 5, 7, 10};
    for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++) {
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
                temp = nums[inner];
                nums[inner] = nums[outer];
                nums[outer] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    puts("\nHere is the list after the sort:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

**Book code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

main() {
    int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
    int nums[10];
    time_t t;
    // If you don't include this statement, your program will always
    // generate the same 10 random numbers
    srand(time( & t));
    // The first step is to fill the array with random numbers
    // (from 1 to 100)
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        nums[ctr] = (rand() % 99) + 1;
    }
    // Now list the array as it currently is before sorting
    puts("\nHere is the list before the sort:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }
    // Sort the array
    for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++) {
        didSwap = 0; //Becomes 1 (true) if list is not yet ordered
        for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++) {
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
                temp = nums[inner];
                nums[inner] = nums[outer];
                nums[outer] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Now list the array as it currently is after sorting
    puts("\nHere is the list after the sort:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

**Tweaked book code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

main() {
    int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
    int nums[10];
    time_t t;
    srand(time( & t));
    nums[0] = 0; //set the first element of the array to the lowest value possible
    for (ctr = 1; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        nums[ctr] = (rand() % 99) + 1;
    }
    puts("\nHere is the list before the sort:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }
    for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++) {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++) {
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer]) {
                temp = nums[inner];
                nums[inner] = nums[outer];
                nums[outer] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    puts("\nHere is the list after the sort:");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++) {
        printf("%d\n", nums[ctr]);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

---

From the book,

> The next program sorts a list of 10 numbers. The numbers are randomly
> generated using rand(). The bubble sort routine is little more than a
> nested for loop. The inner loop walks through the list, swapping any
> pair of values that is out of order down the list. The outer loop
> causes the inner loop to run several times (one time for each item in
> the list).
>
> An added bonus that is common to many improved bubble sort
> routines is the testing to see whether a swap took place during any
> iteration of the inner loop. If no swap took place, the outer loop
> finishes early (via a break statement). Therefore, if the loop is
> sorted to begin with, or if only a few passes are needed to sort the
> list, the outer loop doesn’t have to finish all its planned
> repetitions.

The second paragraph has to do with `didSwap` as it determines whether or not the program finishes early, if it's equal to zero.

---

The first example (from top to bottom) yields an unsorted array because no integer is less than the first element `0` in the array `int nums[10]` and so `nums[inner] < 0` is false for every `inner` from 0 to 9 (inclusive). As a consequence, `didSwap` remains equal to zero, which finishes the program early: `if (didSwap == 0) { break;}`. However, according to the book, this means that the array was already sorted, but this is not the case.

Have I missed something? If not, I would like to know how would you modify the code to allow for what the book says in the second paragraph: "If the loop is sorted to begin with, or if only a few passes are needed to sort the list, the outer loop doesn’t have to finish all its planned repetitions." I haven't been able to think of something.

Comment: the book text and code is plain wrong, you example demonstrates its wrong

Comment: @pm100 Not to mention that `(rand() % 99) + 1` can't yield 100, 99 at most.

Comment: I could be wrong about this. The comment says this is a _bubble_ sort [which _does_ have an "early/no swaps" escape flag]. But, the code in the `for` loops is _not_ for a bubble sort. A bubble sort swaps _adjacent_ elements. But, the code does _not_ do that. And, the loops are backwards. After the first outer loop pass, it assumes the _first_ element is correctly placed. But, for bubble sort, it is the _last_ element that is correctly placed. So, we do _not_ start the 2nd loop at 1 [and increase]. We _reduce_ the length by 1 on each pass.

Comment: Here is some better code: `int length = 10; for (;  length >= 2;  --length) { didSwap = 0; for (inner = 0; inner < (length - 1); inner++) { if (nums[inner] > nums[inner + 1]) { temp = nums[inner]; nums[inner] = nums[inner + 1]; nums[inner + 1] = temp; didSwap = 1; } } if (didSwap == 0) break; }`

Comment: Rather than reinventing a buggy-wheel, just learn how to write a `qsort()` `compare()` function and use `qsort()` for your sorting in C. It will be *Orders Of Magnitude* faster than a hand-rolled sort and much less error prone. See [Answer: qsort() compare()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67895815/3422102) for help understanding how to write and use the `compare()` function.